# PHP inside a User loop — what am I doing wrong?

Tags: add-on, php, solspace-user

On an article page, I'm trying to output "more from this author" using the User add-on from Solspace.

Unfortunately, there's a bug in the current version that prevents this from working:

```
{exp:user:entries channel="articles" status="open" user_author_id="1" entry_id="not 344"}
    {if count == "1"}
    // header and opening ul
    {/if}

        // list items with links to articles

    {if count == total_results}
    // closing ul
    {/if}
{/exp:user:entries}
```

The bug means that `entry_id` doesn't work with the "not" in there, so I can't exclude the current entry.

The workaround is to use PHP, and so I have something like this:

```
<?php $c = 0; ?>
{exp:user:entries channel="articles" status="open" user_author_id="1" limit="4"}
  {if entry_id != "344"}
    <?php $c++; ?>
    <?php if($c == 1): ?>
      <h3>More from this Author</h3>
      <ul class="author-more">
    <?php endif ?>

        <li><?php echo $c ?> <a href="/article/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>

  {/if}
{/exp:user:entries}
<?php if($c != 0) :?>
      </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

Unfortunately, the results I'm getting are odd. I'm getting a list of three articles — the article with the id of 344 is being correctly omitted — but I'm not getting the header and open `ul` tag.

I'm echoing `$c` in there, and what results is a list of three articles numbered 2, 3, 4. It seems like `$c` is skipping straight from 0 to 2.

Hopefully I'm just doing something dumb...

Comment: I'm unclear why adding `{if entry_id != "344"}` required you to switch to PHP inside the loop? The workaround for being unable to use `not` in the `entry_id` param is the `if` statement, yes?

Comment: I needed the PHP to keep an independent count. With just the ExpressionEngine logic, even though the statement `{if entry_id != "344"}` will eliminate the entry I don't want to include, it won't affect the main loop, and EE's count will still iterate as normal. One result being if the article I want to eliminate is the *only* article by this author, even though the `if` statement will prevent it from being displayed, the EE count is still "1", and I get a header and empty `ul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to stick to EE code with the following?

Maybe relying on `total_results` & `count` would do it, and then within you could check for the current entry_id to skip that one.

```
{if total_results>1}
{if count==1}
<!-- Set up header & UL -->
{/if}
{if entry_id != 344}
<!-- Output entry details -->
{/if}
{if:elseif count==1 && total_results==1}
{!-- This would never happen, right? Because if total_results==1, then you're looking at the only entry. So all you need is the single if --}
{/if}
```

Just to clarify what I've written there: I included an else statement for when there's only 1 result. But you'd never want that. Because the 1 result would be 344, and you don't want to show anything if that's the case.

If you kill the `elseif`, you can just do 2 separate `if` statements, right?

```
{if count==1 && total_results>1}
<!-- Set up header & UL -->
{/if}
{if entry_id != 344}
<!-- Output entry details -->
{/if}
```

Is that what you're looking for? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You have a really good point in that if the total count is 1, it's the entry you're on.

Comment: That was it. Just needed more logic, not more code.

Answer (score 3):

Oof, that's a lot of ugly PHP to have to add to get around a bug. May I suggest a couple of alternatives?

One would be to just fix the bug while you wait for Solspace to release an update. (Ha.)

But failing that, use the Query module to grab all of an author's entries and pass them to a standard channel entries loop (which you can then use your standard `limit`, `orderby`, etc on).

```
{embed="_embeds/_more_by_author" entry_ids="{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT entry_id as user_entry_id FROM exp_user_authors WHERE author_id = {author_id} and entry_id != {entry_id}" backspace="1"}{user_entry_id}|{/exp:query}"}
```

(Since we're using variables from your currently-displayed entry, this would have to be inside your primary Channel Entries loop.)

Then in your embed:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles" status="open" entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}"}
    {if count == "1"}
    // header and opening ul
    {/if}

        // list items with links to articles

    {if count == total_results}
    // closing ul
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. the sql statement is blowing up, unfortunately. if i remove ` and entry_id != {entry_id}` it seems to work.

Comment: if i hard code values, it does not blow up.

Comment: ahh, I think i know why it's blowing up, it's my bad — belay those comments.

Comment: Currently belaying.

Comment: ok, i'm close, but {member_id} isn't parsing. here's my php error: SELECT DISTINCT entry_id as user_entry_id FROM exp_user_authors WHERE author_id = {member_id} and entry_id != 15326 (this is when I run the query inside the embed statement)

Comment: Perhaps that should be `{author_id}`.

Comment: if i move the query string outside the embed statement it works fine. i don't know enough to know what determines when a tag will work within another ExpressionEngine tag or not (i tried sticking the value in a stash just for kicks, but it didn't work).

Comment: When you say "outside" and "inside" the embed, do you mean as I have the example code above (with the query module tag pair inside the `entry_ids` embed parameter), or actually inside the embedded file itself? Can you post your complete relevant template code somewhere (in a gist or something)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant inside the parameter, as you have it above: https://gist.github.com/murtaugh/e9f98c95812669ec9aa5

Comment: OK, I see you're using `{embed:entry_id}` in that gist ... are you embedding the embed? Basically you just have to get 2 accurate variable to parse in the SQL statement, and they both require that the embed *statement* be within your primary Channel Entries tag: `{author_id}` (I had `{member_id}` before, this is wrong), and `{entry_id}`.

Comment: Good thing another solution came up because the alchemy of embeds in embeds makes my head hurt :D